# P5.js set() causes drawing to stop working

Tags: javascript, p5.js

Here is my example code:

```
function setup() {

  createCanvas(500, 500);
  background(255);

  fill(255, 0, 0);
  rect(100, 100, 100, 100);

  set(0, 0, color(0));
  updatePixels();

  fill(255, 0, 0);
  rect(300, 100, 100, 100);

  set(0, 0, color(255));
  updatePixels();

}
```

This program should draw two red squares on the screen. It should look like this:

[image: Correct Screenshot]

After drawing the first square, the pixel at position (0, 0) is also manually set to black using the function [set()](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/set). To make the change take effect, [updatePixels()](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Image/updatePixels) is called. After the second square is drawn, the pixel (0, 0) is set back to white, and updatePixels() is called again.

But when you look at the actual result, the second square is missing:

[image]

After some time, I actually found a solution to this problem, but I don't understand why it works. Before calling set(), you have to insert a [loadPixels()](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/loadPixels).

```
function setup() {

  createCanvas(500, 500);
  background(255);

  fill(255, 0, 0);
  rect(100, 100, 100, 100);

  loadPixels();
  set(0, 0, color(0));
  updatePixels();

  fill(255, 0, 0);
  rect(300, 100, 100, 100);

  loadPixels();
  set(0, 0, color(255));
  updatePixels();

}
```

I thought you only have to call loadPixels() if you want to load the pixel data into pixels[]. Additionally, the p5.js reference for [set()](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/set) doesn't tell you that you have to call loadPixels() before using set() in order to use it properly. 
So, why does calling loadPixels() solve the problem? Is this problem maybe a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you check the docs , it says
Loads the pixel data for the display window into the pixels[] array. `This function must always be called before reading from or writing to pixels[]` . Note that only changes made with set() or direct manipulation of pixels[] will occur.

 so this should always be declared before set

> read more https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/loadPixels

Comment: Oh, I see. I should read the docs more thoroughly. But I also think that the p5.js reference should add a loadPixels() to their examples on the set() docs page. Maybe I will write to them.